# What is the difference between the normal input and the height input of a "bump" node?

Tags: shaders

For the *height* input, I know that you plug in a B&W texture.

For the *normal* input, do you plug in the purple-y color normal map? Or do we plug that map into the color input of the "normal map" node instead? If so, what's the function of the *normal* input
of the "bump" node?

Comment: I know that you can use it to plug a Normal Map, as you say, in order to mix a Bump and a Normal map, you can also plug another Bump Map, I don't know if it has another role...

Comment: normal map is basically a bump map, but with more info and better result (short answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html) says, the *Normal* input is

> Standard normal input.

If you don't connect a normal map to a bump map's *Normal* input, the default behavior is to use the same normal map that's produced by the *Texture Coordinates* node's *Object* output.

So the input has the same uses for a bump map as it does for any other node that has a Normal Input: it provides the bump map with a starting point normal map that the height map is used to modify.

Answer (score 7):

*Normal map*, the blueish textures, that represent curvature of surface, should be plugged in material via **Normal map** node. You cannot use normal maps directly, because you should convert them from local (tangent space) to world space using **Normal map** node.

[image]

And you can add some surface curvature on top of existing curvature, using **Bump** node. And it should be added after normal map processing in **Normal map** node:

[image]

So, **Normal** plug used for normals, but converted from tangent space. You can apply as many **Bump** nodes as you want using this way:

[image]

And also there is a bunch of nodes having similar input, for example **Bevel** node which can be used to soften edges in Cycles:

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thank you